# facebook feed page from javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk, fb.ui

Since 17 july, 2017 facebook no longer listens to the parameters for picture/name/description/etc when calling the feed dialog. I can still share the page, but it uses the cached data.

Is there any way to let facebook re-crawl the page before sharing or an way to let facebook know the picture or description of the page has changed (without using the Facebook debug tool)? So my users can still change the picture and then share this page with the new picture without waiting for another 24 hours.

Comment: just use a unique url with unique og tags. trying to recrawl the url whenever you share it is not a good idea.

Comment: I agree that recrawling when sharing is not a good idea, but there must be someway to get new data to facebook...
what do you mean by unique url with unique og tags?

Comment: whenever you share an url with specific og tags, use an url with a parameter for those specific og tags. that is the only way.

Answer (score 1):

Use a unique URL with unique OG tags. Trying to recrawl the url whenever you share it is not a good idea, Facebook wants each URL to have the same OG tags - not different ones for different share events.

Whenever you share an url with specific OG tags, use an URL with a parameter for those specific OG tags. That is the only way as of now.

Comment: and this unique url with unique OG tags should be a different url than the page that the user tries to share? for example:
a user is on https://localhost/testpage and clicks on a share button that shares the page to facebook, do i have to put https://localhost/testpage?og_img='{src}' as href or a different url that is specifically meant for sharing to facebook?
my js code allready generates unique image src urls for facebook so the unique og_img tag shouldnt be a problem.

Comment: no, the url that the user tries to share must be exactly that unique url, of course...because facebook takes the og tags from that unique url.

Comment: but localhost would not work anyway, localhost only exists on your computer

Comment: I know localhost wouldn't work, but had to take some url so it would be clear what to post :)
i've tried to use: 
FB.ui({ method: 'share', href: '{pageurl}?og_img={uniqueimagesrc}',  }, function (response) {   });
where uniqueimagesrc is a different image than is shown on the page or cached in facebook, but facebook still uses the cached image.

Comment: then it´s an issue on your server, make sure you include the correct og:image and do not update it with javascript. you have to do it server side, the facebook crawler does not parse javascript.

Comment: you mean the og:image in the header of the page has to be the same as in the href property?

Comment: you need to use the "uniqueimagesrc" parameter in your server code, that´s what i mean. just try it and use the debugger to rescrape it.